# Вульгарный глагол для "покончить с собой"

Tags: обсценная-лексика

Есть ли  в русском языке вульгарный глагол для обозначения совершения самоубийства?
Спасибо.

Comment: А какие глаголы вы относите к вульгарным?

Comment: Из вопроса следует, что вы хотите выразить это обязательно одним словом (глаголом). Если вас устоят и словосочетания, то желательно это пояснить в вопросе.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. А что за произвол Марка Из? Почему он позволяет себе переформулировывать чужие вопросы? Я привел пример польского аналога zajebać się , а он его удалил.

Answer (score 3):

На все вкусы: руки (на себя) наложить, в жмура сыграть, ссуичидничать - это не вульгарные, но можете пользоваться.